# building a very simple parser in C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to build a very simple parser in C for a class. All it has to do is read in a flag from an input file, determine if the flag precedes an int, char, or float and then write int/float/char to the appropriate .txt file. for example I 9898 would be printed to int.txt. Whenever use the testing script the instructor provided i get these errors:

`parser.c:1:1: error: unknown type name ‘e’
parser.c:1:10: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘on’
parser.c:1:10: error: unknown type name ‘on’`

This is my code please let me know. Thanks so much:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#include <stdio.h>
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *ints.txt = fopen("ints.txt" "w");
    FILE *chars.txt = fopen("chars.txt", "w");
    FILE *floats.txt = fopen("floats.txt", "w");

    char flag;
    int ipint;
    char ipchar;
    float ipfloat;
    int exitStatus = fscanf(input.txt, "%c", &flag);

    while (exitStatus != EOF)
    {
        if (flag == I)
        {
            fscanf(input.txt, "%i", &ipint);
            fprintf(ints.txt, ipint);
        }
        if (flag == C)
        {
            fscanf(input.txt, "%c", &ipchar);
            fprintf(chars.txt, ipchar);
        }
        if (flag == F)
        {
            fscanf(input.txt, "%f", &ipfloat);
            fprintf(floats.txt, ipfloat);
        }
    }
    fclose(input.txt);
    fclose(ints.txt);
    fclose(floats.txt);
    fclose(chars.txt);
}
```

Comment: `#include` belongs at the beginning of the file, not inside `main`. Also a heads-up: regular variable names can't have a `.` in them. And `I`, `F`, and `C` will be considered undeclared variable names in C.

Comment: There are several other problems in your code, fopen can fail, you need to check the return code. And you need to put char characters between quotes, like this: `if(flag == 'I')`

Comment: And it is also forbidden to have dots in your variable names, this is not valid: `FILE *ints.txt`.

Comment: don't write parsers in C. this has already been done and the proability that you can do better is small. look at `lex` and `yacc` instead, to generated parsers from tokens and grammars.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin - He said it's for a class assignment, so I doubt he has a choice of languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the standard headers at file scope, not a block scope:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Suggested changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE fp_input = NULL;
    FILE fp_ints = NULL;
    FILE fp_chars = NULL;
    FILE fp_floats = NULL;

    char flag;
    int ipint;
    char ipchar;
    float ipfloat;
    int exitStatus;

    if (!(fp_input= fopen("input.txt", "r")) {
      perror ("fp_input failed");
      return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp_ints = fopen("ints.txt" "w")) {
      ...
    if (fscanf(fp_input, "%c", &flag)!= 1) { 
      ...

    while (exitStatus != EOF){
      switch (flag) {
        case 'I' :
          fscanf(fp_input,"%i",&ipint);
          fprintf(fp_ints, "%d", ipint);
          break;
        case 'C' :
          ...
        default :
          ...
    }
```

In other words:

1) The `#include` is in the wrong place

2) I would not use variable names like `input.txt` with a period in the name.

3) I think you meant constant `'I'` instead of the variable `I`

4) You should check for errors whenever/wherever possible (like `fopen`, `fscanf`, etc)

5) You need a format string for your `fprintf()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Other than the fopen, and the above comments, is there anything else that sticks out at you?

Answer (score 0):

- Use `switch` statements rather than multiple `if`

```
while (exitStatus != EOF)
{
    switch (flag) {

        case 'I':
            //...
            break;

        case 'C':
            //...
            break;

        case 'F':
            //...
            break;

        default:
            puts("Flag not recognized");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
}
```

- `fprintf` is the same as `printf` and only difference is that you get to decide `stdout`, so character formatting is still required
- Variable names cannot have `.` character in them as this is reserved for accessing members of an object
- `exitStatus` needs to be updated at each iteration so that the program will know when to stop reading from the file. I used `fgetc` and `ungetc` for that

This code should do what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *ints = fopen("ints.txt", "w+");
    FILE *chars = fopen("chars.txt", "w+");
    FILE *floats = fopen("floats.txt", "w+");

    int flag, ipint, exitStatus;
    char ipchar;
    float ipfloat;

    if (NULL == input) {
        perror("File not found [input.txt]");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((exitStatus = fgetc(input)) != EOF && ungetc(exitStatus, input))
    {
        fscanf(input, "%d", &flag);
        switch (flag) {

            case 'I':
                fscanf(input, "%i", &ipint);
                fprintf(ints, "%i", ipint);
                break;

            case 'C':
                fscanf(input, "%c", &ipchar);
                fprintf(chars, "%c", ipchar);

                break;

            case 'F':
                fscanf(input, "%f", &ipfloat);
                fprintf(floats, "%f", ipfloat);
                break;

            default:
                puts("Flag not recognized");
                fclose(input);
                fclose(ints);
                fclose(floats);
                fclose(chars);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(ints);
    fclose(floats);
    fclose(chars);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, is there something wrong with my if statements or does switch just work better? Because if there's nothing wrong with my ifs I'd like to keep them, we haven't learned switch statements yet.

Comment: Yup nothing is wrong with `if` statements. It is just a matter of preference that I recommended `switch`. I like using `switch-case` statements because they look more readable and the program looks less clustered

Comment: @Smac89: There is a bug in your program, if the flag is invalid you don't close the files. Also returning -1 from main is not standard, you should return EXIT_FAILURE, (which is 1 for posix systems).

Comment: @Smac89 switch-case is a little faster than if, since switch-case can compile directly to a `jmp` instruction, but `if` might not.